# Will I need to use a double gate for my fence opening?

Tags: gates, gate-post

I want to make a gate to replace the fence panel for my bike. I also want to utilise the concrete posts as they are straight and I don’t want to dig them out.

W1640 (~65") x H1820 (~72")

Would it need a double gate at the mat width?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the green wooden slats?

Comment: `Is this a doable task you all think?!` ... not answerable ...  depends on the skill of whoever is doing it ... opinion based questions, such as this are off topic here ... please ask a question that has very limited number of "correct" answers ... actually, both of your questions are not answerable due to lack of information

Comment: I removed the part of your post asking _us_ what _you_ are capable of, but the rest is still a bit vague. Obviously gates larger than 164cm exist, so you'll need to ask something more objective. Of critical importance is post integrity. Is there any movement if you hang your weight on them? Please revise to add more information.

Comment: Also of critical importance is the type of bike involved, assuming the motorized variety. :P

Comment: Photo is not great on detail, but it looks to me like a concrete panel below the green slats?

Comment: Isn't there already a gate on the left side?